# fireEvent.Click is not directing me to another page

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have been trying to call a click event that in my Navigation component, I checked that the button is firing but i am not being redirected to another page. Instead my terminal is sending me a snapshot of the component i am testing and not being able to find the login text in h1 tag. Also tried to fire the link instead by giving it a data-testid which also didnt work and gave me back the same results.

Please any guidance, thanks in advance.

test

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import Navigation from './Navigation';

describe('Navigation Content',  () => {
    test('clicking login button', () => {
      const props = jest.fn();
      const { getByTestId, getByText } = render (
        <Navigation popUpHandler={props}/>, { wrapper: BrowserRouter }
      );
      
      const loginBtn = getByText('LOGIN');
      fireEvent.click(loginBtn);

      expect(getByText('Login')).not.toBeNull();
      expect(getByText('Login')).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
})
```

Component i am testing

```
function Navigation(props) {
  const { popUpHandler } = props;

  return (
    <nav className="header__nav">
      <Link data-testid="login-btn" to="/login">
        <button type="button" className="header__login" onClick={() => {console.log('click')}}>LOGIN</button>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/register">
        <button type="button" className="header__register">SIGN UP</button>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/about-me">
        <button type="button" className="header__aboutme">ABOUT ME</button>
      </Link>
      <button type="button" data-testid="close-nav-btn" className="close__nav" onClick {popUpHandler}></button>
    </nav>
  );
}

Navigation.propTypes = {
  popUpHandler: Proptypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Navigation;
```

Trying to redirect to this component to access the h1

```
function LoginForm() {

  return (
    <div className="login">
        <h1 className="entryheader__header">Login</h1>
    </div>
  )
export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: How you are trying to redirect?? Are you using routes?

Comment: wouldnt fireEvent just click the button and automatically direct based on the Link in my navigation component?

Comment: I dont think so. simply giving path inside <link/> will redirect. You have redirect using props.history. Or you can use href

Comment: but it works in my app when i start it

Comment: you mean it's redirecting when you are starting the app?

Comment: check this out https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic. It might help

Comment: sorry you are confusing me, but yes i am using routes to route my to the page i want

Comment: If you are only rendering the navigation links, then what are you navigating to? There is nothing else but the router wrapping the component under test. The navigation component doesn't hide any buttons so they will always be rendered if it is. You'll probably also want to use the `MemoryRouter` when testing since your tests likely aren't running in a browser.

Comment: but my routes and everything is set up, and my app works the way i want it to, its just my tests that are not running the way i want it to

Comment: @DrewReese so basically you are saying that, for me to be able to grab from another component, i would have to render that component as well. So if i wanted to check if this button actually routes me to the page i want how would i do so? With enzyme i was able to check the path of the link, but with RTL ii dont know how to do that because mainly i can only grab by text or testid

Comment: TBH I don't see much here to test... seems you are trying to test 3rd-party code, i.e. test that the react-router-dom `Link` does what it is supposed to. But yes, if you want to test that clicking the login link *actually* does something then you need enough code that *actually* does something when the link is clicked.

Comment: @DrewReese The main reason why i want to create this test is because i read that RTL is mainly testing based on user behaviouver, thus im trying to avoid grabbing from code and instead grab from dom

Comment: Right, and that is fine, but don't test 3rd-party code, i.e. don't test javascript language functionality, don't test react functionality, don't test react-router-dom functions/components, etc... you want to test the behavior and logic of ***your*** code.

Comment: @DrewReese Given that RTL main focus is to grab from testid and text, is there a way to check if the value of 'to' in Link is equal to '/login'. i just want to test for textcontent anyways. Unless there is no reason to do that as well. 

As for what i was trying to test earlier is when my click event fire and directs me to another link, i was hoping to grab the h1 tag that has the text content of 'login', with that i thought that i could verify it took me to the correct link

Comment: The primary purpose of RTL is to test your UI the same way users or other parts of your app interact with it, i.e. via props and the rendered UI. The navigation links alone don't offer much in the way of testability other than a basic "renders without crashing" test case. If you mock up enough "UI" code to click a link and navigate elsewhere, well, now you are no longer "unit" testing and are encroaching upon integration testing, i.e. how parts of the app *actually* work together. Like I said, there isn't much of anything to test from what I can tell.

Comment: thats true... i keep forgetting that, and keep trying to test whatever i see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224721/discussion-between-bpun1p-and-drew-reese).

Comment: maybe this could help you testing links : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871929/2295549

Comment: Either test the Login component separately or do an e2e with Cypress.