# How to Test Anchor Hrefs in an antd Menu with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

I'm having trouble building unit tests to check if my a href links in my Antd Menu are going to the right places. I used the antd Menu with SubMenu that contains two dropdown items. When either one is clicked, they go to their respective urls. Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Menu} from antd;

export default function App(){
    <Menu>
      <Menu.SubMenu key = 'google' title = {"Google Links}>
         <Menu.ItemGroup>
           <Menu.Item><a href = {https://www.google.com/}> Homepage Link </a></Menu.Item>
           <Menu.Item><a href = {https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en}> Images Link</a</Menu.Item>
         </Menu.ItemGroup>
      </Menu.SubMenu>
    <Menu>
}
```

Here is what I'm trying in my App.test.js unit test

```
describe('Google Links', ()=>{
   it('Links Work', () =>{
    const wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
    const menuFound = wrapper.find(Menu)
    menuFound.simulate('click',{key:'google'});
    expect(wrapper.find(Menu).at(0).props().href).toBe('https://www.google.com/');
    expect(wrapper.find(Menu).at(1).props().href).toBe('https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en');
    });
});
```

I've also tried:

```
describe('Google Links', ()=>{
   it('Links Work', () =>{
    const {getByText} = render(<App/>);
    expect(getByText('Homepage Link')).toHaveAttribute('href','https://www.google.com/');
    expect(getByText('Images Link)).toHaveAttribute('href','https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en');
    });
});
```

Neither of these methods work and I feel like I've tried everything I could find through documentation and other stack overflow posts.

Comment: I think you can import `screen` and do `screen.getByText` or `screen.getByRole` for the links. That ought to return you the link or if you want multiple ones then `getAll`. Also, if you want to debug, it is better to check what does `getByText('Homepage Link')` returns. It might not be returning a valid element maybe.

Comment: @jaybhatt I get the error: TestLibraryElementError: Unable to Find element with the text: Homepage Link. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher for flexible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Submenu are hidden from initialy, and any children of them is not present in VDOM, so you need to fire `mouseover` to make sub-menu items rendered: `fireEvent.mouseOver(getByText('Google Links'));`

Next, the `firaEvent` are async, so you need to await for it complete, something like: `await waitFor(() => getByText('Homepage Link'));`

And all together:

```
describe('Google Links', () => {
  it('Links Work', async () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<App />);

    fireEvent.mouseOver(getByText('Google Links'));
    await waitFor(() => getByText('Homepage Link'));

    expect(getByText('Homepage Link').href).toEqual('https://www.google.com/');
    expect(getByText('Images Link').href).toEqual('https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en');
  });
});
```

Comment: You could also trigger a click event on your link, then spy on history.push calls : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871929/2295549, to be closer to what a real user would do and see (the react-testing library way :).