# react-js testing library unable to test useState hook and asynchronous axios signIn function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-state, react-testing-library

I cant seem to get the test for my reactjs login component to work.
I am using react-testing-library only and not Enzyme.

I want to be able test 3 things:

1. That the **signIn** is clicked once and the axios ajax call uses the mocked ajax
2. That I can set a value using useState and check the value was set
3. That the page rendered after a successful login has the text **welcome**

None of the above is working. I have been working through different issues eg this **expect(signIn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)** returns:

```
    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Other times it throws **Error: Unable to find the "window" object for the given node.** for this:

```
const button = screen.getByRole('button', {name: /submit/i})
```

Here is what Login.test.js looks like

```
/** 
 * @jest-environment jsdom
*/

import React from 'react';
import { screen, render, waitFor, fireEvent, getAllByLabelText } from '@testing-library/react';
import {renderHook} from '@testing-library/react-hooks'

import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

import Login from "../components/auth/login"
import Index from "../components/index"
import {userContext} from "../utils/context/UserContext"
import axios from 'axios';

const user = {user: {} }
const isLoggedIn = false
const setIsLoggedIn = jest.fn()
const setUser = jest.fn()
const setState = jest.fn();

jest.mock('axios');

describe("Login", () => {

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('ajax login', async () => {

    const {container} = render(
      <userContext.Provider value={ {user, isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, setUser} } >
        <Login />
      </userContext.Provider>
    )

   axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({
      status: 200,
      data: {user: {name: 'Rony', email: 'rony@example.com' } }
   }))

   setIsLoggedIn.mockReturnValue(true)
   const signIn = jest.spyOn(React, "useState")
   signIn.mockImplementation(isLoggedIn => [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn]);

   const email = container.querySelector('input[name=email]')
   const password = container.querySelector('input[name=password]')
   const button = screen.getByRole('button', {name: /submit/i})

   await act(async () => {
     userEvent.type('email', 'abc@yahoo.com')
     userEvent.type('password', 'abcddef')
     userEvent.click(button)
   });

   expect(signIn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
   expect(setIsLoggedIn).toEqual(true);
   expect(screen.getByText(/welcome/i)).resolves.toBeInTheDocument
    
  })
})
```

The login component is shown below:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import axios from 'axios'
import {userContext} from "../../utils/context/UserContext"

export const Login = (props) => {
  const {user, setIsLoggedIn, isLoggedIn, setUser} = useContext(userContext)

  const token = Cookies.get('csrf_token') || props.csrf_token || ''

  const[loginData, setLoginData] = useState({email: '', password: '' })

  const[csrf_token, setCsrfToken] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setCsrfToken(token)
  }, [])

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    setLoginData({...loginData, [name]: value})
  }

  const signIn = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let headers = {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token
      }
    }

    let url = "/api/v1/sessions"
  
    axios.post(url, {user: loginData}, headers)
      .then(response => {
        setLoginData({email: '', password: ''})

        setIsLoggedIn(true)
        setUser(response.data.user)

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      setIsLoggedIn(false)
    })
 
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div> </div>
      <form onSubmit={signIn}>
        <h3>Login</h3>

        <div className="mb-3 form-group col-xs-4">
          <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" 
              value={loginData.email} onChange={handleChange} aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
          <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
            value={loginData.password} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-3 form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
          <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </div>
        
        <button name="submit" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={signIn} >Submit</button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

UserContext.js

```
import React from 'react';
export const userContext = React.createContext(undefined)
```

The index.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import axios from 'axios'
import {userContext} from "../../utils/context/UserContext"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "../components/auth/login";

export default const Index = (props) => {

  let form_token = Cookies.get('csrf_token') || ''
  let check_login = props.isLoggedIn || false
  let check_user = props.user || ""

  const[isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(check_login)
  const[user, setUser] = useState(check_user)
  const[isError, setIsError] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setCsrfToken(form_token)
  }, [isLoggedIn, csrf_token, user])

  return (
      <userContext.Provider value={{user, setUser, isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn}}>
      <Router>
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/'>
               
            </Route>

            <Route path='/login'>
              <Login />
            </Route>

          </Switch>
        </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
      </userContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not mock React's useState function, and you cannot test redirection because you are rendering only the Login component in your test.

Beside this I don't thinks you can mock a function defined in a functional component (`signIn`), and even if it was possible you should not test internal implementation, but only what a real user whould see : here, you can test that the inputs have the correct value after the `userEvent.type(...)`.

Just remove the `useState` and `signIn` mocks, then in your Login component add a redirection after a successful login. Then you just have to enter user information, click the submit button (as you already do), then you can check that history.push have been called correctly (see [Simplest test for react-router's Link with @testing-library/react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869886/simplest-test-for-react-routers-link-with-testing-library-react/61871929#61871929)).

Comment: Thanks @Florian. I will make some of the changes locally but I will wait to see if other suggestions come up.