# How to test navigation with Jest and RTL

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test my app component and navigate through my application. I start at '/' path and navigate through '/signin' and then to '/installations' path successfully. Then I want to check a third path which is '/dashboard/:installationId' by clicking to a button and I got blocked in the '/installations' page. I just repeated the same process (by clicking a button and wait to be redirected) by unsuccessfully. Any idea will be welcome...

The test in question:

```
it( 'Full app rendering/navigating', async () => {

        const history = createMemoryHistory()

        render(
            <Router history={history}>
                <App />
            </Router>,
        )

        // Check we are on the good location at the begining of the test
        await waitFor(() => expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/'))

        // env variable needed to connect to the account
        const email = process.env.TEST_EMAIL
        const password = process.env.TEST_PASSWORD


        // // signIn button from the landing page
        const signInButton = screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'Sign in' })
        expect(signInButton).toBeInTheDocument()

        // // click action of this button
        const leftClick = {button: 0}
        userEvent.click(signInButton, leftClick)

        // // check the path
        await waitFor( async () => expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/signin'))




        // // check the presence of elements in signin page
        const emailField =    screen.getByPlaceholderText('Email address')
        const passwordField = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Your password')

        expect(emailField).toBeInTheDocument()
        expect(passwordField).toBeInTheDocument()

        // fill the credentials
        userEvent.type(emailField, email)
        userEvent.type(passwordField, password)

        const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' })
        expect(button).toBeInTheDocument()


        // fire event login by clicking the button
        userEvent.click(button)
        
        
        // check the path
        await waitFor(() => expect(button).not.toBeInTheDocument())

        // check the title of installation page to be in the document
        const title = screen.getByText('Installation selection')

        expect(title).toBeInTheDocument()

        const infoText = screen.getByText('Please, wait a little bit while we are fetching {{data}}')
        expect(infoText).toBeInTheDocument()

        // expect installations are loaded
        await waitFor(() => expect(infoText).not.toBeInTheDocument())


        await act( async () => {

            const maisonPassive = screen.getByText('Maison passive')
            expect(maisonPassive).toBeInTheDocument()
    
            const maisonPassiveButton = maisonPassive.closest('a')
            expect(maisonPassiveButton).toHaveAttribute('href', '/dashboard/31929')
    
             ### nothing happened ###
            // fire event login by clicking the button
            userEvent.click(maisonPassiveButton, { button: 0 })

            
        })


        ### blocked here ###
        // await waitFor (async () => expect(window.location.pathname).not.toBe('/installations'))


    })
```

Comment: You could try to mock history.push and assert on its calls : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869886/simplest-test-for-react-routers-link-with-testing-library-react/61871929

Comment: No I try to reproduce your code in my use case and it didn't work, i'm still blocked at the installations page