# How to test a react router link with testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

### *I want to test a react router link with testing library, I tried:*

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Routes, NavLink, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <NavLink to={"/"}>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to={"/about"}>About</NavLink>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element="home page" />
        <Route path="/about" element="about page" />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**App.test.js:**

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Route, Router } from "react-router-dom"
import App from './App';

test('first home link', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ["/"] });
  render(
    <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  );
  const linkElement = screen.getByRole("link", { name: /about/i });

  userEvent.click(linkElement);
  
  screen.debug();
});
```

**Output of screen.debug:**

```
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <a
              aria-current="page"
              class="active"     
              href="/"
            >
              Home
            </a>
            <a
              class=""
              href="/about"
            >
              About
            </a>
          </nav>
          home page
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

*the page ***didn't change*** to about page like you see on the output the screen.debug*

***Is there is a way to fix that?***

#### dependencies:

1. "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4"
2. "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0"
3. "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0"
4. "history": "^5.3.0"
5. "react": "^18.1.0"
6. "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
7. "react-dom": "^18.1.0"

Comment: Check if this solution applies to your problem, it seems like it should work

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869886/simplest-test-for-react-routers-link-with-testing-library-react)

Comment: I asked a similar question and got a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77894819/unit-test-navlink-navigation-in-react/77896386?noredirect=1#comment137328675_77896386