# Unit Test NavLink Navigation in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I am using React v18.2.0 and React Testing Library v5.17.0.

How should I unit test the NavLinks in my navigation bar?

I think this test should work, but I am getting the error:

```
Expected: "about"
Received: "about", {"preventScrollReset": undefined, "relative": undefined, "replace": false, "state": undefined, "unstable_viewTransition": undefined}
```

Looks like an object is being passed as well as the route and it is causing the test to fail?

My NavBar:

```
const NavBar = () => {

  return (
    <>
        <div className="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to="home" className="navlink">Home</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to="about" className="navlink">About</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

My unit test:

```
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import * as router from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

describe(NavBar, () => {
    const mockedNavigation = jest.fn();
    
    const MockedNav = () => {
        return(
            <Router>
                <Navbar />
            </Router>
        )
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.spyOn(router, 'useNavigate').mockImplementation(() => mockedNavigation)
    })
        
    it('should navigate to the about page', () => {
        const { getByText } = render(<MockedNav />);
        fireEvent.click(getByText(/About/i));

        expect(mockedNavigation).toHaveBeenCalledWith("about");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The function you are mocking ***is*** passed these other arguments.

## Solutions

- You can simply add the additional arg to the test:

  ```
  describe(NavBar, () => {
    const mockedNavigation = jest.fn();

    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.spyOn(router, 'useNavigate').mockImplementation(() => mockedNavigation
    }

    it('should navigate to the about page', () => {
      const { getByText } = render(<Navbar />, { wrapper: Router });
      fireEvent.click(getByText(/About/i));

      expect(mockedNavigation).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        "about",
        {
          preventScrollReset: undefined,
          relative: undefined,
          replace: false,
          state: undefined,
          unstable_viewTransition: undefined
        }
      );
    });
  })
  ```
- You can assert the mock was called and that the *first* argument is what you expect:

  ```
  describe(NavBar, () => {
    const mockedNavigation = jest.fn();  

    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.spyOn(router, 'useNavigate').mockImplementation(() => mockedNavigation
    });

    it('should navigate to the about page', () => {
      const { getByText } = render(<Navbar />, { wrapper: Router });
      fireEvent.click(getByText(/About/i));

      expect(mockedNavigation).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(mockedNavigation.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual("about");
    });
  });
  ```
- Or you can use an [asymmetric matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectanything) to assert anything passed in the second arg (*since it appears you don't care what that specific value is*):

  ```
  describe(NavBar, () => {
    const mockedNavigation = jest.fn();

    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.spyOn(router, 'useNavigate').mockImplementation(() => mockedNavigation
    }

    it('should navigate to the about page', () => {
      const { getByText } = render(<Navbar />, { wrapper: Router });
      fireEvent.click(getByText(/About/i));

      expect(mockedNavigation).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        "about",
        expect.anything(),
      );
    });
  })
  ```

Comment: Drew, you are a genius mate! It works. Does the NavLink pass this object by default then?

Comment: @ScottishSmile It may, I believe. It might also just be that you are spying into internal implementation details as well.